# Effective way for display data in item by select statement in oracle forms builder

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I want to know a Effective way for display data in item by select statement in oracle forms builder.
I've use following pl/sql:

```
BEGIN

    SELECT  AMEND_DATE,AMEND_NARRATION,OPENER_CUST_FLAG,OPENER_CODE, 
            CUSTOMER_CODE,OPEN_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, EXPIRY_PLACE

    INTO    :EXPORT_LC.AMEND_DATE, :EXPORT_LC.AMEND_NARRATION ,:EXPORT_LC.OPENER_CUST_FLAG , 
            :EXPORT_LC.OPENER_CODE , :EXPORT_LC.CUSTOMER_CODE ,:EXPORT_LC.OPEN_DATE , 
            :EXPORT_LC.EXPIRY_DATE , :EXPORT_LC.EXPIRY_PLACE

    FROM    SALES_CONTRACT

    WHERE   TRIM(SALES_CONTRACT_REF_NO) = TRIM(:EXPORT_LC.ADV_SALES_REF_NO)
    AND     TRIM(OWN_BRANCH_CODE) = TRIM(:EXPORT_LC.BRANCH_CODE); 

EXCEPTION 

    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        VALERT:=SHOWALERT('No data found for sales contract no. '||:EXPORT_LC.ADV_SALES_REF_NO||'. Please check...','1');
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
        WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
            VALERT:=SHOWALERT('Duplicate record found for sales contract no. '||:EXPORT_LC.ADV_SALES_REF_NO||'. Please check...','1');
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
END;
```

Is there any effective way? Please if anybody know please reply/answer.

Comment: Why do you see this way not effective?

Comment: I want to see at a glance that which value is assign in which item(above pl/sql has few field but if there is more than 100 column in table than its difficult to find which value is assigned in which item) like calling procedure, where parameter value assigned like following:
 proc_a(AMEND_DATE => :EXPORT_LC.AMEND_DATE,
             AMEND_NARRATION => :EXPORT_LC.AMEND_NARRATION);

Comment: I'm afraid its not possible. You can only format select by placing selected columns on the same positions in same rows like target fields

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Petr Pribyl

Comment: can't you use a database block for that select?